# OTRS Bug parsing zeroes on email

Tags: regex, perl, otrs

I have just setup my first installation of OTRS and I was setting up my first filtering when I found a 'possible' bug:

When the regex matches a zero (as in '0') and I try to assign it to a DynamicField (type text) using '[***]' I get an empty value (maybe it believes it's NULL??)

The actual regex works:

```
Node users: (.*?)\,
```

And what I'm parsing on the body:If I have a '1' it works fine

```
"...3.250. Node users: 1,  Backend use..."
```

log:

```
Filter: 'variable name 4' Set param 'X-OTRS-DynamicField-variable4' to '1'
```

If I have a '0' OTRS doesn't see a value

```
"...3.250. Node users: 0,  Backend use..."
```

log:

```
Filter: 'variable name 4' Set param 'X-OTRS-DynamicField-variable4' to ''
```

Any ideas? I'm no perl expert, but it looks like it's both successfully matching and unsuccessfully inserting in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code, I'm left with guessing. My guess would be there's some logic:

```
if ( $variable ) { # do something };
```

Which means when the variable is present, but `0` it's evaluating as false when it shouldn't be. This can be easily fixed by tracking down the offending line and changing it to:

```
if ( defined $variable ) { #do something };
```